# replace whole string if contains substring

Tags: powershell

I want to completely replace a string if it contains a specific substring, using replace. How can this be done?

I have tried the following, with expected output "STRING":

```
$a="abc123STRINGabc123"
$a.replace('*STRING*','STRING')
```

Comment: Try: `$a -replace '.*(STRING).*', '$1'`

Comment: Thanks that was simple but only works with "-replace" and not ".replace" .. wonder why?

Comment: @SAS b/c the `-replace` operator does regular expression replacements whereas the `.Replace()` method by default does simple string replacements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-replace` operator and a regular expression.

```
$a = 'abc123STRINGabc123'
$b = 'abc123foobarabc123'

$srch = 'STRING'
$repl = 'GNIRTS'

$pattern = '.*{0}.*' -f [regex]::Escape($srch)

$a -replace $pattern, $repl   # output: GNIRTS
$b -replace $pattern, $repl   # output: abc123foobarabc123
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I really want a more compact one-liner code since I will do several replaces on the object.

Comment: @SAS Things don't get much more compact than `$string -replace $pattern, $replacement`. What are you talking about?

Comment: ok, I edited to something like $a -replace(('.*{0}.*' -f [regex]::Escape('xxx')),'XXX'), now I can do this with several replaces with very little code, thanks.

Comment: @SAS The escape step in my example is for escaping special characters in the search string (before inserting it into the pattern string). If you know that your search strings don't have special characters in them you can omit that step: `$a -replace '.*foo.*', 'bar' -replace '.*some.*', 'other'`.